# CGPoint PreviousLocation - UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, cgpoint

I know it seems like it's a fairly easy to do, but i can't seem to figure it out and i've researched a lot of places but really what i want it's no where. 
i'm creating a puzzle game and the images are moved around using UIGestureRecognizers but let's say if the puzzle piece does not fit into the right location, i want it to move to it's original position or previous position where i got it from. Can someone please shed some light on this on ho to do this? Thanks

Comment: How about saving the original position of the puzzle before you move it around?

Comment: Your Idea worked as well, however i didn't know exactly how to do that, but with a little research it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to add a property to your view controller to store the CGPoint of the puzzle piece before you move it. Check for `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` in the state of the recogniser(which i think you must already be doing in order to start moving the puzzle piece) and update the property with the touch location from the view.

Comment: It worked thanks....the only other thing i didn't do, which i should have done to begin with was declare a global CGPOint variable so i can access it within any function. Thanks man.